# Salvar uma lista no SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite3

Tenho uma lista de produtos e utilizo `recycleViwer` para lista-los.
Quero pegar esses produtos e salva-los no banco de dados.
Sendo honesto, não sei fazer! Estou pesquisando mas não acho conteúdo.

Estou na minha activity onde esta os produtos e vou passar eles para uma `FragmentDialog`.

```
private void abrirFormularioDialogCompra() {
    Bundle argumentos = new Bundle();
    FormularioCompraDialog formularioCompraDialog = new FormularioCompraDialog();
    argumentos.putSerializable("valor", valorCarrinho);
    **List<Produto> produtosSelecionados = getProdutos();
    argumentos.putSerializable("listaProdutos", (Serializable)** produtosSelecionados);
    formularioCompraDialog.setArguments(argumentos);
    formularioCompraDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

Recebendo:

```
private void pegaOsProdutos() {
    assert getArguments() != null;
    **Serializable listaProdutos = getArguments().getSerializable("listaProdutos");**
}
```

Como eu pego esses produtos agora e salvo eles no SQLite
???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, não entendi direito se a sua dúvida é fazer qualquer manipulação (select,insert e update) no banco de dados do android (sqlite) ou se você sabe fazer isso mas só esta com problema pois os dados que você quer salvar estão em uma List.

Vamos por partes então, se o seu problema é como abrir uma conexão com o banco e fazer as manipulações, primeiro você vai precisar criar uma classe e herdar de **SQLiteOpenHelper**:

```
public class minhaclasse extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
   @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

Como pode ver no exemplo acima, nela vai ter 2 métodos para você sobrescrever `public void onCreate()` e `public void onUpgrade()`.
Esta é a classe que ficará responsável por criar o banco e abrir conexões com o mesmo.
Depois será necessário você criar suas classes para persistência de dados (DAO), não vou colocar o código destas na resposta pois ficaria muito extenso e cada programador/projeto vai fazer/ser de um jeito, o que não falta são exemplos disso na internet, pode pesquisar por CRUD Android, mas vou deixar [este exemplo](https://www.freakyjolly.com/android-sqlite-example-application-insert-update-delete-truncate-operations/) que acredito que esteja bem fácil de entender.

Agora se você já sabe abrir conexões com o banco, fazer insert, delete e update e a sua dúvida é como fazer isso com os dados no List, a resposta é fazer um loop nesta lista e para cada iteração você chama a sua função de insert no banco de dados passando os parâmetros, por exemplo id_carrinho, id_produto, valor.

**Editado**
Primeiro vamos só confirmar algumas coisas:

1 - A classe do objeto que você esta enviando tem que implementar `Serializable`, assim:

```
public class Produto implements Serializable{

  //Seu código da classe produto

}
```

2 - Na classe que esta enviando os dados, precisa utilizar `ArrayList` no lugar de `List`. (provavelmente você terá que alterar seu método getProdutos() para retornar ArrayList)

```
ArrayList<Produto> produtosSelecionados = getProdutos();  
argumentos.putSerializable("listaProdutos", (Serializable) produtosSelecionados);
```

3 - Na hora de receber os dados você já converte para um `ArrayList<Produto>`.

```
ArrayList<Produto> listaProdutos = (ArrayList<Produto>) getArguments().getSerializable("listaProdutos");
```

Agora que você tem os dados em formato ArrayList novamente pode percorre-los com um foreach e salva-los assim:

```
for(Produto produto : listaProdutos){
  metodoInsertBD(produto);
}
```

Comment: Meu amigo muito obrigado pela sua mensagem. A questão é justamente fazer uma inserção com os dados que estão no List. Os atributos são descrição, preço e quantidade.
Sobre o banco tenho sim o conhecimento no CRUD completo e ele esta até feito certinho no app, mas essa lis que pegou.
Você disse que é só fazer um loog e chamo a função de insert no banco que contem os campos do dados que estão no list. Você teria como me mostrar um exemplo disso meu caro? Ficaria agradecido, mas já vou ir tentando algo aqui

Comment: @DevelopD, entendi, vou editar minha resposta e incluir como você pode fazer!

Comment: @DevelopD, acho que agora o exemplo está mais próximo da sua necessidade.

Comment: Perfeito meu amigo, acredito que isso já me abriu muito o leque rsrsrs.
Agora só preciso salvar esses produtos no banco com a tabela que eu criei, eu só preciso levar o Id da compra junto rsrs, pois para cada compra, tem os seus determinados produtos. Pitando uma dificuldade nisso você me ajuda?
Que Deus te abençoe meu querido, muito obrigado mesmo

Comment: @DevelopD, claro, precisando só chamar! Só lembrando que se a resposta lhe ajudou com seu problema não esqueça de marca-la como correta para ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida!!

Comment: Perfeito meu caro, marcada =)